# Automatically Adding Articles into Community Navigational Topics

Tags: community, knowledge, articles, topics

According to Salesforce Docs, adding articles to a topic from the Community Management page only adds **CURRENT** articles of your chosen Data Category.

[Set Up Navigational Topics](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_topics_navigational.htm&language=en_US)
[image: Docs]

So thinking out of the box, is there any way of automatically adding an article to a navigational topic when they get published?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I guess the API is not exposed either via REST or Connect in Apex to do this .

Comment: Sigh. not possible then, Oh well, I've already posted an idea, doubt will get delivered soon.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LjJ4AAK

Answer (score 2):

This idea already delivered by the Automatic topic assignment feature.
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_networks_automatic_topic_assignment.htm